# Parse out of a textfile necessary parts

Tags: bash, parsing

I got this output from address sanitizer:

I need the line with keyword `SUMMARY`. The content i need to parse is:

```
 AddressSanitizer 

 heap-buffer-overflow 

 main.cpp

 5
```

Is it possible to do it with bash tools or something like that?

I ask, because it always has the same output structure and only needs this line with those keywords

```
    =================================================================
    ==11642==ERROR: AddressSanitizer: heap-buffer-overflow on   adress    
    0x61400000ffd4 at pc 0x47b8e5 bp 0x7fff67190bb0 sp 0x7fff67190ba8
    READ of size 4 at 0x61400000ffd4 thread T0
        #0 0x47b8e4 in main /home/pse/dockerfiles/memory_analysis_addressSanitizer/./main.cpp:5
        #1 0x7f78b6c8bec4 (/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6+0x21ec4)
        #2 0x47b44c in _start (/home/pse/dockerfiles/memory_analysis_addressSanitizer/a.out+0x47b44c)

    0x61400000ffd4 is located 4 bytes to the right of 400-byte region [0x61400000fe40,0x61400000ffd0)
    allocated by thread T0 here:
        #0 0x465aa9 in operator new[](unsigned long) (/home/pse/dockerfiles/memory_analysis_addressSanitizer/a.out+0x465aa9)
        #1 0x47b76e in main /home/pse/dockerfiles/memory_analysis_addressSanitizer/./main.cpp:3
        #2 0x7f78b6c8bec4 (/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6+0x21ec4)

    SUMMARY: AddressSanitizer: heap-buffer-overflow /home/pse/dockerfiles/memory_analysis_addressSanitizer/./main.cpp:5 main
    Shadow bytes around the buggy address:
      0x0c287fff9fa0: fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa
      0x0c287fff9fb0: fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa
      0x0c287fff9fc0: fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
      0x0c287fff9fd0: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
      0x0c287fff9fe0: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
    =>0x0c287fff9ff0: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00[fa]fa fa fa fa fa
      0x0c287fffa000: fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa
      0x0c287fffa010: fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa
      0x0c287fffa020: fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa
      0x0c287fffa030: fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa
      0x0c287fffa040: fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa
    Shadow byte legend (one shadow byte represents 8 application bytes):
      Addressable:           00
      Partially addressable: 01 02 03 04 05 06 07 
      Heap left redzone:     fa
      Heap right redzone:    fb
      Freed heap region:     fd
      Stack left redzone:    f1
      Stack mid redzone:     f2
      Stack right redzone:   f3
      Stack partial redzone: f4
      Stack after return:    f5
      Stack use after scope: f8
      Global redzone:        f9
      Global init order:     f6
      Poisoned by user:      f7
      ASan internal:         fe
    ==11642==ABORTING
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use this awk command:

```
awk -F '[ :]+' -v OFS='\n\n' '/SUMMARY/{sub(/.*\//, "", $4); print $2, $3, $4, $5}' file
AddressSanitizer

heap-buffer-overflow

main.cpp

5
```